# Closing sale order without delivery order or invoice in odoo 10

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

Is it possible to close sale order without creating DC or Invoice and also making sure the stock picking/stock move is done in inventory in ODOO 10 ?

I tried directly putting sale order status to 'done' state, which is not working since the product in inventory needs to be reduced. Could anyone suggest ?

Comment: you should choose cancel, done means sale order is delivered and invoiced

Comment: @KLN I want it to be closed, just that my customer don't need DC or Invoice. As per your suggestion, If I cancel it.. the product count from stock won't be reduced.. right ? I need stock.picking and stock move to work as per the flow without dc or invoice. Would that be possible ?

Comment: is it confirmed SO?

Comment: Yes bro, it is a confirmed SO.

Comment: automate what are functionality in return in stock